# JWT authentication not working despite sending JWT token

Tags: jwt, silhouette

My Angular client is sending `JWT` token in a header but I am getting `401` from the server. What could I be doing wrong?

[image]

[image]

I tested the `jwt` at `jwt.io`. It is showing it as vaid for my secret key.

The payload shown in `jwt.io` is

```
{
  "sub": "1-dl/HfaGzfERQfZhLK0X+RPgALQr1vfuHG3hRgJYNwZQFU6NDIAkH54V4BykkwmZCWdvnogzFWn0Kr20PTr0YCM0mUWc=",
  "iss": "play-silhouette",
  "exp": 1526458444,
  "iat": 1526415244,
  "jti": "b9956c6dea46f108729f97f3742dbea8c0d75053b08aee51d0e4999e0e71d062a48ab0b40b049c6d3709d28d502264b1fd687cf5710c1319513bc95fdcacde5ac5ff41f70cdf404e5591d5ee41a31b7f56c47bb364c9736b36537186b1c9312baf2630f826a3b0c28250501df87a5e0f0e1bbabff2021a834764454f340b260a"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I had to send the token in `X-Auth-Token` header in subsequent requests and not  in `Authorization` header